# Spatial query sub query not func

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, subquery, spatial

I am trying to add a subquery to the below to work out the population of each county - I can run the code sperate and get the right answer, though when I try and incorporate it into the existing query, it returns the population of the country instead;

So this code separately works fine

```
select a.name, sum(b.totadult)
from admin.oas_centroids_stats as b
join admin.councils as a
on st_contains(a.geom, b.geom)
group by a.name;
```

[separate code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imwAE.png)

This is the query I am attempting to add it too;

```
select a.name, count(b.distname), round(st_area(a.geom) / 1000000), round((st_area(a.geom) / 1000000)/(count(b.distname))),
(select sum(c.totadult) from admin.oas_centroids_stats as c join admin.councils as a on st_contains(a.geom, c.geom))
from admin.councils as a
join map.railwaystations as b on st_contains(a.geom, b.geom)
group by a.name, st_area(a.geom);
```

[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DHHA.png)

Any help would be appreciated on this one!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the data as text, not as images. Also, provide some data sample, so that we can reproduce your results and the exact expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the group by in your select subquery hence the full population rather than population per country.

If you want this done with subquery something similar to below should give you what you are looking for.

```
select a.name, count(b.distname)
         , round(st_area(a.geom) / 1000000)
         , round((st_area(a.geom) / 1000000)/(count(b.distname)))
        , c.cnt as population
from admin.councils as a
join map.railwaystations as b on st_contains(a.geom, b.geom)
join (select a.name, sum(b.totadult) as cnt
        from admin.oas_centroids_stats as b
        join admin.councils as a
        on st_contains(a.geom, b.geom)
        group by a.name) as c on c.name =  a.name 
group by a.name, st_area(a.geom);
```

But you should be able to do this with a window function which would be a better approach.

Comment: Thanks so much - feel like an idiot now, knew it was obvious in the end!